# How to create a 3D grid in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, grid

What is a easy way to generate a 3D "hollow" and square grid around a central point, more like a cube (that can vary in size), with each cell being evenly spaced (based on a value)?

Note: I know how to make a 2D grid but not a 3D one.

Edit: I'll try to explain it more: I'm looking for a way to create a grid at every face of a cube (6 faces) at runtime, that lets suppose is 3x3x3m, and each cell being every 1 meter apart from each other. Something like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want this to look like?

Comment: Think of a hollow cube made of "cells" or empty gameObjects.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. ;) Search for an image similar to what you want, and embed it in your question above. It can also help to describe a bit about what you're using this grid for, as this can help us decide which of several approaches is better suited to your needs.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: This looks like something you could create just by making a tiling texture with one square / cross of your grid, and repeating it over the surface of a cube, using the texture transform properties on the material to control the grid spacing. Does this not meet your needs?

Comment: I actually need the empty gameobjects as some sort of "socket" evenly spaced at each face of the cube.

Comment: Then make those game objects in the usual way, either via the create menu, or using `new GameObject()` in a script. Do you need any specific help with how to create a game object? If so, it sounds like a different issue than drawing a grid, so you may want to edit your question to reflect this or ask a new one.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to generate these objects by code at runtime.

Comment: That's not in your question above, so it will not be answered in its current state. I'll repeat: edit your question to describe this, or post a new question describing this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by looping over each axis and creating a gameobject at those points like so.

```
public GameObject block;
public uint Width = 3;
public uint Height = 3;
public uint Depth = 3;

void Start () 
{
    for (uint x = 0; x < Width; ++x)
    {
        for (uint y = 0; y < Height; ++y)
        {
            for (uint z = 0; z < Depth; ++z)
            {
                if (x > 0 && x < Width - 1 && 
                    y > 0 && y < Height - 1 && 
                    z > 0 && z < Depth - 1) 
                    continue;

                Instantiate(block, new Vector3(x,y,z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where block is the empty gameobject or "socket". This will spawn objects only at the edge of the rectangle.